# Rails patient id in url dissapears on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my patient controller i have defined an action called "erstellen", with an view. This action/view is for the doctor to assign treatments to an patient. Therefore it is important that the patient_id is passed to this action.

In my patient/show page i created this link:

```
  <%= link_to('Erstellen', erstellen_patients_path(@patient), :class => "btn btn-small btn-info" ) %>
```

What produces this output:

```
 http://localhost:3000/patients/erstellen.6
```

**First** i dont understand why there is an dot and not an slash?

And  **second**  problem is that the '.6' dissapears when i reload the page so that an treatment cannot be assigend to an patient!

My routes:

```
  post "patients/erstellen"

   resources :patients do
    collection do
     get :search2
     get :erstellen
   end
  end
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `erstellen` action is supposed to act on a certain patient. Therefore it's not collection scope, it's member scope.

```
resources :patients do
  collection do
    get :search2
  end
  member do
    get :erstellen
  end
end
```

Then

```
erstellen_patient_path(@patient)
```

> First i dont understand why there is an dot and not an slash?

The parameter you pass to collection action is recognized as a format specifier, since the route does not expect any patients.

Comment: Excellent!! I will upgrade your answer as soon as i have 15 points thanks!

Comment: Oh no i get the error: No route matches [POST] "/patients/6/erstellen" How do i have to change my post 'route'?

Comment: Thanks but seems not to work now, when istart the server, i get the error: rake aborted missing :controller

Comment: Well, you messed up somewhere else :)

Comment: I think the problem is that :erstellen is not an controller, it is an action of patient controller

Comment: No, I don't think it's that

Comment: I removed "post :erstellen" form my routes file, and now i can start my sercer again. But netherless i get the error when i try to safe an treatment to an patient: No route matches [POST] "/patients/6/erstellen"

Comment: Sorry i made an mistake! Thanks